# A question on plane curves.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, plane-curves

Consider a closed, simple, smooth curve $C$. Can someone help me prove the following:

For all point in $C$ and their respective neighborhoods, the radius of curvature cannot be infinite.

I basically came up at this point while trying to find some properties of closed curves. But, as one might've understood already that i want to prove that a closed simple plane curve MUST have either a vertex, or a curved region(radius of curvature is finite). Can someone give some hints as to how to prove this, or just disprove this claim?

Comment: NOTE: this isn't a homework question, and i'm just asking for hints on how to approach this.

Comment: Perhaps consider the point farthest from the origin.

Comment: ok, ill consider that, thanks, any other ideas are also welcome.

Comment: $C$ might contain a piece of a straight line.  Here the radius of  curvature is infinite.  Are you referring to the four-vertex-theorem? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four-vertex_theorem

Comment: No, i just want to prove that a closed simple plane curve cannot be composed of ONLY finite flat regions, that is it must have a vertex or a finite region with finite radius of curvature.